# Could not read freemarker template

Tags: freemarker

My file is under
src/main/resources/freemarker/email_notification.txt

I am not able to read the freemaker file, that is email_notification.txt, which contain html file.

My Reference is from here: http://websystique.com/spring/spring-4-email-using-velocity-freemaker-template-library/

I have tried the velocity method but there is strikethrough in some of the words, thus i choose freemarker method instead.

```
 @Transactional
    @Service("EmailService")
    public class EmailService{

        @Autowired
        JavaMailSender mailSender;

        @Autowired
        Configuration freemarkerConfiguration;


    public void sendEmail(Map<String, Object> params) {



        MimeMessagePreparator preparator = getMessagePreparator(params);

        try {
            mailSender.send(preparator);
            System.out.println("Message has been sent.............................");
        }
        catch (MailException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


    private MimeMessagePreparator getMessagePreparator(final Map<String, Object> params){

        MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {

            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

                helper.setSubject(params.get("trnmaster").toString());
                helper.setFrom("XXXXX@gmail.com");
                helper.setTo("XXXXXX@hotmail.com");


                String text = geFreeMarkerTemplateContent(params);//Use Freemarker or Velocity
                System.out.println("Template content : "+text);

                helper.setText(text, true);

            }
        };
        return preparator;
    }


    public String geFreeMarkerTemplateContent(Map<String, Object> model){
        StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
        try{
         content.append(FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString( 
                 freemarkerConfiguration.getTemplate("/email_notification.txt"),model));

         return content.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception occured while processing fmtemplate:"+e.getMessage());
        }
          return "";
    }



}
```

part of the config file

```
@Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean getFreeMarkerConfiguration() {
        FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean bean = new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean();
        bean.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:/freemarker/");
        return bean;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you configure FreeMarker, you should use: `bean.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:/freemarker/");`

Also that example is quite strange. Why's the file extension `txt`? It should be `ftlh` for a HTML template (was `ftl` in older projects). Also I would definitely overwrite `FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean.postProcessConfiguration` and do the recommended setup according to https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_quickstart_createconfiguration.html, except that you must not call `setDirectoryForTemplateLoading`, and maybe `setDefaultEncoding` is already set by Spring as well. It's important to ensure that you get automatic HTML escaping (`incompatibleImprovements` set to 2.3.24 or higher and the `ftlh` file extension does that).